# Installing Ubuntu Server on a secondary HDD within Ubuntu Desktop

Tags: server, system-installation

I have a spare hard drive on which I'd like to install Ubuntu server. Is it possible to plug the hard drive into my PC as a secondary drive, download the ISO and install Ubuntu server onto the secondary hard drive from within my main Ubuntu Desktop install?

Comment: Are you looking for a dual-boot?? What do you mean by "from within main ubuntu"??

Answer (score 1):

You can use Startup Disk Creator. It's pre-installed on (most) Ubuntu. You have to select the ISO and the drive where yout want the ISO to be installed an click on CREATE.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the solution called **Without CD** here:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromLinux

That's the only solution I've found that doesn't require you to reboot before actually installing the system. The other solutions on that page describe alternatives where you copy an installer onto the new disk and boot from it.

> **Without CD**
>   
> You can install Ubuntu directly from Ubuntu using debootstrap. Debootstrap installs some essential packages in a
>   directory for use with chroot. Note that the essential packages does
>   not in itself make the system bootable. It just installs what you need
>   to chroot to that directory and use apt-get to install other packages
>   which make ubuntu usable.
>
> Step 1. First check that you have debootstrap installed.
>
> sudo apt-get install debootstrap (NOTE: if you want to install a newer
>   release than your current system, you normally need to install the
>   backported debootstrap version, see: UbuntuBackports)
>
> Step 2. Partition device and make a filesystem.
>
> We will assume /dev/sda is the storage device for your fresh install.
>
> Remove former partitions and create the new one.
>
> sudo fdisk /dev/sda
>
> WARNING: DOS-compatible mode is deprecated. It's strongly recommended
>   to
>            switch off the mode (command 'c') and change display units to
>            sectors (command 'u').
>
> Command (m for help): p
>
> Disk /dev/sda: 250.0 GB, 250000000000 bytes 255 heads, 63
>   sectors/track, 30394 cylinders Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 =
>   8225280 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>   I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes Disk identifier:
>   0x00031196
>
> Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
>   /dev/sda1   *           1        2550    20482843+  83  Linux
>   /dev/sda2            2551       30394   223656930   8e  Linux LVM
>
> Command (m for help): d Partition number (1-4): 1
>
> Command (m for help): d Selected partition 2
>
> Command (m for help): n Command action    e   extended    p   primary
>   partition (1-4) p Partition number (1-4): 1 First cylinder (1-30394,
>   default 1):  Using default value 1 Last cylinder, +cylinders or
>   +size{K,M,G} (1-30394, default 30394):  Using default value 30394
>
> Command (m for help): p
>
> Disk /dev/sda: 250.0 GB, 250000000000 bytes 255 heads, 63
>   sectors/track, 30394 cylinders Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 =
>   8225280 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>   I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes Disk identifier:
>   0x00031196
>
> Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
>   /dev/sda1               1       30394   244139773+  83  Linux
>
> Command (m for help): w The partition table has been altered!
>
> Calling ioctl() to re-read partition table.
>
> WARNING: Re-reading the partition table failed with error 16: Device
>   or resource busy. The kernel still uses the old table. The new table
>   will be used at the next reboot or after you run partprobe(8) or
>   kpartx(8) Syncing disks. Make the filesystem
>
> sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda1 Step 3. Mount that new partition.
>
> sudo mkdir /mnt/installer sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/installer Step 4.
>   Download and install base system packages.
>
> sudo debootstrap lucid /mnt/installer Step 5. Copy files to the new
>   install to keep your repositories
>
> sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list /mnt/installer/etc/apt/ Step 6. Chroot
>   to your new install.
>
> sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/installer/dev sudo mount --bind /dev/pts
>   /mnt/installer/dev/pts sudo mount -t proc proc /mnt/installer/proc
>   sudo mount -t sysfs sys /mnt/installer/sys sudo chroot /mnt/installer
>   Step 7. Upgrade the new install. Install language-pack-en-base to
>   prevent warnings about locale settings during the upgrade.
>
> apt-get update apt-get install language-pack-en-base apt-get upgrade
>   You may have also noticed that the wrong timezone was selected when
>   tzdata was setup. Run this to correct your timezone.
>
> dpkg-reconfigure tzdata If you are using Software RAID and/or LVM, you
>   should install these packages before installing a kernel:
>
> apt-get install mdadm lvm2 Step 8. Install Grub and Linux Kernel.
>
> apt-get install grub-pc linux-image Step 9. Add user and/or set root
>   password.
>
> To add a user and set a password for that user.
>
> adduser  You may also want to add your user to the sudo
>   group so that user can run programs as root.
>
> gpasswd -a  sudo To set a root password:
>
> (NOTE: You must at least set a root password if you aren't adding a
>   user)
>
> passwd It should now be safe to reboot